# Check for balanced parentheses in an expression C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, stack

Hope you are doing great. I have struggling with this code. I think this must work but i cant see the problem exacty (I am like blind ) where i have mistake.
Can you Please help with this.... Thanks in advance.
BOTH String returns FALSE. but first must be TRUE.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class PatternFinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Check()
    {
        String test_good = "()(){}{}{()}";//this must return TRUE
        String test_bad = "((({}{}))()";//this must return FALSE

        Debug.Log(checkBalanced(test_good));
        Debug.Log(checkBalanced(test_bad));
    }

    public static bool checkBalanced(String check)
    {
        Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
        for (int i = 0; i < check.Length; i++)
        {
            char character = check[i];
            if (character == '[' || character == '{' || character == '(')
                stack.Push(character);
            else if (character == ']' || character == '}' || character == ')')
            {
                if (stack.Any())
                    return false;
                switch (character)
                {
                    case ']':
                        if (stack.Pop() != '[')
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case '}':
                        if (stack.Pop() != '{')
                            return false;
                        break;
                    case ')':
                        if (stack.Pop() != '(')
                            return false;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (stack.Any())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (stack.Any()) { return false; }` looks suspicious. Why would you say the expression is unbalanced if you encounter `)` and there were previously `(`?

Comment: Also, it may be more useful for you to learn how to debug code yourself instead of having us do it. Here's a popular blog post on the subject: <https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/>.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want the stack.Any() right after you enter this if statement. It causes you to return from the function too early. Because it exists the function if there is anything in the stack without removing anything.

```
        else if (character == ']' || character == '}' || character == ')')
        {
            if (stack.Any()) // you don't want this here
                return false;
```

Having stack.Any() before you pop out anything from the stack does not serve a purpose there because you want to go through the string until you reach one that isn't matching.

Instead, you should have **!stack.Any()** because if the stack is empty and you have a closing character then it is not balanced.

```
public static bool checkBalanced(String check)
{
    Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();
    for (int i = 0; i < check.Length; i++)
    {
        char character = check[i];
        if (character == '[' || character == '{' || character == '(')
            stack.Push(character);
        else if (character == ']' || character == '}' || character == ')')
        {
            if (!stack.Any()) // if stack is empty and you have a closing character this means that it is unbalanced 
                return false;
            switch (character)
            {
                case ']':
                    if (stack.Pop() != '[')
                        return false;
                    break;
                case '}':
                    if (stack.Pop() != '{')
                        return false;
                    break;
                case ')':
                    if (stack.Pop() != '(')
                        return false;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    // it is balanced only if there aren't any left
    if (!stack.Any())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But that line would make sense if there were no items on the stack and it checked for that. `if(!stack.Any())` would be good.

Comment: @mlibby no, you want to go through the entire string before you make a decision about whether it is balanced or not.

Comment: @mlibby instead what you want is to continue to the next iteration of the loop if the stack is empty.

Comment: In the original the only characters on the stack are [, {, or (, so if you find a character ], }, or ) and the stack is empty, that's unbalanced.

Comment: @mlibby thank you, I corrected my answer. Both of the stack.Any() should be !stack.Any()

Comment: OMG Thank you so much. really.

Comment: @israfiluzuk no problem. I am glad that I could help you. If my answer was clear and helpful could you please mark it as the answer to your questions and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool Balanced_Or_Not(Stack<char> EXP)
        {
            bool result = true; 
            List<char> Open = EXP.Where(ch => ch == '{' || ch == '[' || ch == '(').ToList();
            List<char> Closed = EXP.Where(ch => ch == '}' || ch == ']' || ch == ')').ToList();
            Closed.Reverse();
            if (Open.Count() == Closed.Count())
            {
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (var item in Open)
                {
                    result = (item == '(' && Closed[counter] == ')') || (item == '{' && Closed[counter] == '}') || (item == '[' && Closed[counter] == ']') ? true : false;
                    counter++;
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else result = false; 
            return result; 
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public static List<char[]> TOKENS = new List<char[]>
        {
            new char[] { '(', ')' }, new char[]{ '{', '}' },new char[] { '[', ']' }
        };

        static bool IsBalance(string str)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                return false;

            Stack<char> stack = new();

            foreach (var item in str.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (IsOpenToken(item))
                {
                    stack.Push(item);
                }
                else if (IsMatch(item, stack.Peek()))
                {
                    if (stack.Count > 0)
                    {
                        stack.Pop();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (stack.Count == 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        private static bool IsOpenToken(char term)
        {
            foreach (var item in TOKENS)
            {
                if (item[0] == term)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        private static bool IsMatch(char closeTrim, char openTrim)
        {
            foreach (var item in TOKENS)
            {
                if (item[0] == openTrim)
                {
                    return item[1] == closeTrim;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IsBalance("[({)}]"));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(IsBalance("({[]})"));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(IsBalance("()(){}{}{()}"));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(IsBalance("((({}{}))"));
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "((())";
            Stack<char> lefts=new Stack<char>();
            Stack<char> rights = new Stack<char>();
            char[] ar = str.ToArray();
            int countl = 0;
            for(int i =0; i<ar.Length;++i)
            {
                if (ar[i] == '(')
                    lefts.Push(ar[i]);
                if (ar[i] == ')')
                    rights.Push(ar[i]);
              
            }
            str = "";
            Stack<char> f = new Stack<char>();
            if(lefts.Count==rights.Count)
            {
                countl = lefts.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < countl; ++i)
                    f.Push(rights.Pop());
                for (int i = 0; i < countl; ++i)
                    f.Push(lefts.Pop());
                for (int i = 0; i < countl*2; ++i)
                    str += f.Pop();
            }
            if (lefts.Count > rights.Count)
            {
                countl = lefts.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < countl; ++i)
                {
                    f.Push(rights.Count > 0 ? rights.Pop() : ')');
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < countl; ++i)
                {
                    f.Push(lefts.Pop());
                }
                   
                for (int i = 0; i < countl * 2; ++i)
                    str += f.Pop();
            }
            if (lefts.Count < rights.Count)
            {
                countl = rights.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < countl; ++i)
                {
                    f.Push(rights.Pop());
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < countl; ++i)
                {
                    f.Push(lefts.Count > 0 ? lefts.Pop() : '(');
                }
                
                for (int i = 0; i < countl * 2; ++i)
                    str += f.Pop();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this for problem. it works properly on all cases.

```
public string checkBalanced(string s)
 {
        string result =  "YES";
        Stack stack  = new Stack();
 
        for(int i = 0 ; i<s.Length;i++){
            
            if(s[i].ToString() == "{" 
               || s[i].ToString() == "(" 
               || s[i].ToString() == "["){
              
                stack.Push(s[i].ToString());
            }
            else if(stack.Count >0){
                     
                if(s[i].ToString() == "}"){
                    
                    if(stack.Peek().ToString() == "{"){
                        stack.Pop();
                    }else{
                        result = "NO";
                    }
                }else if(s[i].ToString() == "]"){
                    
                    if(stack.Peek().ToString() == "["){
                        stack.Pop();
                    }else{
                        result = "NO";
                    }
                }else if(s[i].ToString() == ")"){
                      
                    if(stack.Peek().ToString() == "("){
                    
                        stack.Pop();
                    }else{
                        result = "NO";
                    }     
                }
                }else{
                    Console.WriteLine(count +  " " + s[i].ToString());
                    result = "NO";
                }
            }
        
        if(stack.Count >0){
            result = "NO";
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).